# SQL Execute a Query then execute another based on the results

Tags: mysql, database, migration, multi-table

Im trying to make a Database Migration SQL Script to transfer data from one database to another, the old database has about 10-15 tables the new one has in excess of 300, now im trying to do one big migration i know where eveything needs to go , I just cant figure out how to transfer based on the results.

Heres what ive got at the moment:

```
SELECT i.item_name AS `item_name` , i.item_rrp  AS `item_rrp` , i.item_web_price  AS `item_price` , p.product_image AS `product_image` FROM `table1`.`items` JOIN(
 `table1`.`items` i , 
 `table1`.`products` p
) WHERE `item_discontinued` = 0
```

Now with the results from this i want to do an insert , i know how to do the insert but how do I loop over the results from the first query, I can use PHP but it is preferrable for speed that i use complete SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop, use `INSERT AS SELECT` :

```
INSERT INTO <YourTable> (<column names .......>)
SELECT i.item_name AS `item_name` , i.item_rrp  AS `item_rrp` , i.item_web_price  AS `item_price` , p.product_image AS `product_image`
FROM `table1`.`items` JOIN(
`table1`.`items` i , 
`table1`.`products` p
) WHERE `item_discontinued` = 0
```

Comment: Il give this a try, this will be a very big sql script, its for magento, since their API's arent very slow for mass product conversions